# Projecting a 1:n relationship to a single entity in Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity

I'm new to Entity Framework, so please be indulgent. ;)

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 in a C# desktop application with code first.

Let's suppose I have the following two tables in SQL Server 2008:

**calendarweek**

- id (*long*)
- year (*int*)
- weeknumber (*tinyint*)
- description (*text*)

**calendarevent**

- id (*long*)
- calendarweek_id (*long*, foreign key)
- title (*varchar*)

In the application I have a POCO like this:

```
class Event
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Byte Week { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Is it possible to project this 1:n relationship into a single entity?**

In the times before Entity Framework I simply joined the two tables with ADO.NET and filled the Event object manually.

The most articles I read respectively this topic assume, that you want to map a 1:n relationship on two entities. I also tried entity splitting, but it seems to be intented for the use of 1:1 relationships.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: *Is it possible to ...* are very bad questions - instead ask *how to ...* - BTW, yes it is possible :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ Expression

```
IList<Event> queryA = ( from e in context.CalenderEvents
                        join w in context.CalenderWeeks 
                          on e.CalenderWeek_Id equals w.Id
                        select new Event
                        {
                            Id = e.Id,
                            Year = w.Year,
                            Week = w.WeekNumber,
                            Title = e.Title,
                            Description = w.Description,
                        } ).ToList();
```

or lambdas

```
IList<Event> queryB = context.CalenderEvents
    .Include( e => e.CalenderWeek )
    .Select( e => new Event
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Description = e.CalenderWeek.Description,
        Title = e.Title,
        Week = e.CalenderWeek.WeekNumber,
        Year = e.CalenderWeek.Year,
    } ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The key learning for me: seperate the entity classes from the service domain objects in this case.

Comment: @devnull Yes, start declaring data services (interfaces) and data models (classes) that your application work with. One implementation will maybe use a EF datacontext with some entity classes. But the should be independent.

Comment: Got it working, I preferred the lambda. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to say that one event may last more than one calender week. So we can use an `ICollection` or `DbSet` in `Event class`:

```
class Event
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Byte Week { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CalenderWeek> CalenderWeeks{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Who asks for *may last more than one calendar week*?

Comment: Thanks for you answer Murat, but @Sir Rufo is correct: I indeed have only a 1:n relationship. An event belongs to exactly one calendar week, while a calendar week may have multiple events.

Comment: Opposite is correct `public virtual ICollection<Event> Events{ get; set; }` can be use in Calender class.